# Halo:Reach Matchmaking Campaign

Tags: halo-reach

In some of the release notes Bungie noted that Halo Reach will have campaign matchmaking. I'm assuming this meant you could play the campaign with other random people on Xbox Live, versus just those on your friends list.

Is this the case, and if so, how do I access it?

Comment: I just noticed this in my RSS feeds, it looks like it will be coming out in a couple of weeks. http://kotaku.com/5642276/halo-reach-campaign-matchmaking-to-begin-early-next-month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a bit about what tzenes said:
It is confirmed that Bungie plans to release the campaign matchmaking some time in the future:

"If you're looking for campaign matchmaking in Halo: Reach, sit tight. In an effort to keep your first campaign experience spoiler free, we've decided to wait for a bit before we deploy the campaign playlist.

From here: http://www.bungie.net/News/content.aspx?type=news&cid=28616

Answer (score 3):

So Reach did indeed launch **without** matchmaking for the campaign.  There have been [rumors](http://www.co-optimus.com/article/4580/halo-reach-co-op-campaign-matchmaking-missing-coming-soon.html) that Bungie is planning to proved that after launch, based on [previously made statements](http://www.bungie.net/News/content.aspx?type=news&cid=28616).  However, Bungie has yet to set a date.

You can still do Campaign as Co-Op with your friend; you can also set your campaign (and other modes) to `open` this allows any friends to join your game at their convenience.  Sadly, that is only friend support (unlikely Crackdown 2).

It is worth noting that Firefight did launch with Matchmaking (when it was introduced in  Halo:ODST it did not).  You want `Classic Firefight` as normal is only one set.

Comment: Yes, Firefight in Reach is awesome, and I love the new matchmaking available in it. Much more enjoyable than ODST.

Answer (score 0):

It is just like normal multiplayer, arena, or firefight matchmaking. Sorry for the short answer, I am on business right now and will update the a detailed answer when I get back.

Here is an [interview](http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/action/haloreach/video/6273271) talking about matchmaking

**UPDATE**:
[Campaign matchmaking will appear in October](http://multiplayerblog.mtv.com/2010/09/20/halo-reach-campaign-matchmaking-coming-in-october/)